# Why << operator in ofstream is not const?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I noticed that the `operator <<` in `ofstream` is not `const`. It is obvious that this operator will change the content of the file but what is it changing inside the `ofstream` object?

In other words, if I have `ofstream` as a class member function and I want to call the `<< operator` on it inside a `const` member function I have to alter it to `non-const` member function or mark the `ofstream` as `mutable` but it seems not logical from abstract point of view for me.. did I miss something?

Comment: At the very least, it will be changing the buffer contents of the stream object.

Comment: It can also change the status if the write fails.

Comment: @latedeveloper should I be aware of its internal buffer? I mean they can make it mutable since it is very internal thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it logically changes the stream. To the bare minimum, it changes the write position within the stream buffer. It can also modify the status of the stream (for example, when writing error happens).

But what is even more important (in my view) is the logical mutability. The stream is not the same after the writing - it has the new value in it. If your class doesn't care about this fact, you may declare your stream member `mutable`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it may call [`setstate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate) which isn't `const` for a reason since it changes the internals of the object as noted in [the formatting part for streams](http://eel.is/c++draft/iostream.format#ostream.syn).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that while `ofstream` itself doesn't have to be modified to be written to (even though it probably should), the `ostringstream` which also inherits the `<<` operator from `ostream` class has to be modified in order to be written to, as you need to change the internal `string` object. Because of that, the operator has to be declared `const` to cover all the cases (the operator is defined in `ostream` class).